# Dynamic Programming: Minimum wastage and minimum lot

Tags: php, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem, greedy, minimum-spanning-tree

I am working on a project where I need to create a data in such optimised format that it doesn't slow down the framework too much.
The problem is:
Suppose you have ordered **12 unit** from my ecommerce store of a product. And for that product I have **5 different bundles** to offer this much quantity from.
Suppose the array of bundles with ***serial number as key*** and ***max units available in that bundle as value*** is like:

```
$arr = array(
array('sr_no1'=>5),
array('sr_no2'=>7),
array('sr_no3'=>2),
array('sr_no4'=>9),
array('sr_no5'=>12)
);
```

Now there are two main conditions to my greedy approach to give away the quantity requested by customer.

1. there should be minimum wastage like if you order 11 units then you would give 9+2-11=0 wastage instead of giving it from 12-11=1 wastage
2. value should be chosen from minimum number of lot/bundles like if you order 12 units then there are 5+7-12=0 wastage and 12-12=0 wastage so we'll choose array('sr_no5'=>12) for giving away the requested quantity.

I have been trying to figure out the solution for last 3 days.

> Consider the test cases for quantity ordered to be like 12 or 11 or 6
>   or 35 or 30, etc.

What I need as a result is the arrays that we'll choose to distribute the quantities like array('sr_no5'=>12) for giving away 12 units of quantity ordered and arrays array('sr_no3'=>2),array('sr_no4'=>9) for giving away 11 units of quantity.

I have tried knapsack, greedy, and minimum spanning tree while trying to figure out the solution.
Please find the most optimised solution as we do not want to achieve server time out.

> NOTE: all the values above like **quantity/unit ordered**, **no. of
>   bundles**, **max available unit in each bundle** are variables and can
>   change for any no. of cases.

Comment: Can more than 1 of the same bundle be used for each request?

Comment: No, you have only provided number of units in a bundle

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of an algorithm but you could view all possible outcomes by assigning each bundle a binary with, 0 or 1. 11000 would equal 5+7+0+0+0 (12), 00010 would equal 0+0+0+9+0 etc.

Then build a master array based on that pseudo binary value and the total that gives.

Then filter by match (or nearest match) and see which result has least amount of 1's.
It's crude but would work.

Comment: I doubt that it will satisfy all the test cases. show me a dry run how you thought of the solution for at-least the test cases I mentioned in the question

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a 3 parts algorithm:

1. Get an array with all possible bundles combinations
2. Filter possible solutions: all solutions which gives exactly or more items than needed
3. Order by preference ( [PHP: Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) ):

   1. First those with minimal waste
   2. First those which waste less number of bundles
   3. First those which waste smaller bundles

You can optimize the code unifying parts **1** and **2**, filtering the possible solutions while creating the array. There are probably many possible programming patterns or even libraries to accomplish such a purpose. Depending on the amount of bundles affecting each case, it would be over skilled to optimize that much.

Comment: And less no. of bundles too

Comment: Why the negative?